# Difference Between Betaine & Zwitterion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, ions, terminology

what is difference btw Betaine & Zwitterion, Both having positive and negative charge in a molecule.

[image]

How to categorize Zwitterion and Betaine? or both are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betaine):

> A betaine (BEET-ah-een, /ˈbiːtɑːˌiːn/) in chemistry is any neutral chemical compound with a positively charged cationic functional group [...] **which bears no hydrogen atom** [...]. A betaine thus may be **a specific type of zwitterion**.

Comment: it mean Betaine is a class of Zwitterion, But why it called  Betaine? Also, there is hydrogen atom in Betaine in a given formula,

Comment: @N.ALodhi The cation in the given betaine is bonded to three $\ce{Ph}$ (phenyl) groups, which means no hydrogen atom.